# I will definitely or I would

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

Let's say, your current job does not look promising, and you are planning whether to stay or not. Can you say:

> "If being a medical transcriptionist can make me rich because of excellent pay, then I **will definitely** stay on this job, sadly its not.

Or

> "If being a medical transcriptionist can make me rich because of excellent pay, then I **would** stay on this job, sadly its not.

In the above bold letters written, which is correct?, to make it grammatical...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to shift both tenses.

> If being a medical transcriptionist **could** make me rich because of excellent pay, then I **would** definitely stay on the job, sadly it can not.

I think a little more revision is needed to make this really natural, though.

> If I could get rich being a medical transcriptionist, I would stay on the job.  Sadly, I can't.

or something like

> If medical transcriptionsts were well-paid, I would stay on the job, but they are not.

Comment: You omited something, how about this, ''if medical transcriptionists were well-paid, which could make me rich, I would stay on the job, sadly, they are not.''